# ¿Cómo permitir sólo 15 digitos con el comandos slash bot discord? en python

Tags: python, discord.py

Estoy intenando programar un bot para discord que pertmite eliminar una imagen de imgur con el **deletehash**, lo que estoy intentando hacer es que sólo pueda permitir 15 digitos ya que el deletehash tiene 15 digitos, pero a la hora de añadir menos de 15 digitos me tira error en la consola(CMD)

Este es el error que me muestra:
[image]

Este es el código que estoy usando:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_slash import SlashCommand
from discord_slash.utils.manage_commands import create_choice, create_option
from discord_slash import SlashCommand, SlashContext
import requests

    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '/')
    bot.remove_command("help") # Borra el comando por defecto !help
    slash = SlashCommand(bot, sync_commands=True)
    @slash.slash(
        name="borrar1", description="Escribe La id para borrar la iamgen",
        options=[
                    create_option(
                      name="borrar_imagen",
                      description="Escribe el ID para borrar la imagen",
                      option_type=3,
                      required=True
                    ),
                     
        ])
                      
                
                 
    
        
    
    
    async def borrar1(ctx:SlashContext, borrar_imagen:str):
        url = f"https://api.imgur.com/3/image/{borrar_imagen}"
        while len(borrar_imagen) !=15:
            borrar_imagen = await ctx.send("Sólo 15 digitos")
        payload={}
        files={}
        
        headers = {
            'Authorization': "Bearer "}
        response = requests.request("DELETE", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)
    
        embed=discord.Embed(title="", description="Imagen borrada con exito!", color=0x00ff11)
        if response.json()["status"] == 200:
                await ctx.send(embed=embed, hidden=True)
    
        embed=discord.Embed(title="", description="No está permitido paginas webs", color=0xff0019)        
        if response.json()["status"] == 400:
            await ctx.send(embed=embed, hidden=True)  
    
        embed=discord.Embed(title="", description="Error!", color=0xff0019)   
        if response.json()["status"] == 403:
            await ctx.send(embed=embed, hidden=True) 

bot.run("")
```

Esta es la parte que esta fallando:

```
while len(borrar_imagen) !=15:
            borrar_imagen = await ctx.send("Sólo 15 digitos")
```

No se cómo solucionarlo

Alguien me podria ayudar?, muchas gracias!

Comment: Creo que te podria servir cambiar el while por un if y el != por >=

Comment: Creo que está claro que lo que recibe `borrar1` no es una string, sino un `SlashMessage`. Mirando la documentación, puedes obtener el contenido usando el atributo `Message.content`.

Answer (score 0):

Lo probe de esta manera:

```
if len(borrar_imagen)  !=15:
        await ctx.send("Sólo 15 digitos")
        return
```

Código completo

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_slash import SlashCommand
from discord_slash.utils.manage_commands import create_choice, create_option
from discord_slash import SlashCommand, SlashContext
import requests

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '/')
bot.remove_command("help") # Borra el comando por defecto !help
slash = SlashCommand(bot, sync_commands=True)
@slash.slash(
    name="borrar1", description="Escribe La id para borrar la iamgen",
    options=[
                create_option(
                  name="borrar_imagen",
                  description="Escribe el ID para borrar la imagen",
                  option_type=3,
                  required=True
                ),
                 
    ])
                  
            
             

    


async def borrar1(ctx:SlashContext, borrar_imagen:str):
    url = f"https://api.imgur.com/3/image/{borrar_imagen}"
    if len(borrar_imagen)  !=15:
        await ctx.send("Sólo 15 digitos")
        return
    
    
        
             
    payload={}
    files={}
    
    headers = {
        'Authorization': "Bearer "}
    response = requests.request("DELETE", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)

    embed=discord.Embed(title="", description="Imagen borrada con exito!", color=0x00ff11)
    if response.json()["status"] == 200:
            await ctx.send(embed=embed, hidden=True)
         

    embed=discord.Embed(title="", description="No está permitido paginas webs", color=0xff0019)        
    if response.json()["status"] == 400:
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, hidden=True)  

    embed=discord.Embed(title="", description="Error!", color=0xff0019)   
    if response.json()["status"] == 403:
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, hidden=True) 

        







bot.run("")
```